# is it possable to install a linux distro ie:- nethunter on a android device

Tags: bootloader, shell, command-line

I have been trying to work out how to use my old Android tablet as a stand alone Linux tool for pen-testing and network monitoring and logging. I have it boot straight into the OS without having to run it over the top or along side my android OS for obvious reasons (speed,storage,simplicity)

Comment: What your question? Which specific device is this?